# how to order the items in angularjs onclick

Tags: angularjs

I have lot of records coming from the database. Want to perform sorting based on the priority of the records and vice-versa. My priority is ["H", "M", "L", "NO GO"]. want to show the records based on the priority on-clicking of the button and vice-versa means if first i click need to show the H-M-L-NOGO and toggle clicking should show NO GO-L-M-H. Its not coming perfectly when sorted on priority column.
my script.js is

```
$scope.filterPriority = function () {
        if(toggled) {
            $scope.peoples.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (priorityArray[a.priority] || Infinity ) - (priorityArray[b.priority] || Infinity);
            });
            $scope.sortBy = 'priority';
            $scope.sortDescending = !$scope.sortDescending;
        } else {
            $scope.peoples.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (priorityArray[b.priority] || Infinity ) - (priorityArray[a.priority] || Infinity);
            });
            $scope.sortBy = 'priority';
            $scope.sortDescending = !$scope.sortDescending;
        }   
        toggled = !toggled;
    };
    /* sorting for remaining columns */
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.sortDescending = false;

    $scope.sort = function(column) {
        if ($scope.sortBy === column) {
            $scope.sortDescending = !$scope.sortDescending;
        } else {
            $scope.sortBy = column;
            $scope.sortDescending = false;
        }
    }
```

My approach in plunker url is https://plnkr.co/edit/HPGnCIRNSdCFU6nI1eO2?p=preview

Comment: Check my answer, exactly what you need.

Comment: Did you check the answer? Yaswanth?

Comment: Did you check the attached snippet of my answer? It sorts well

Comment: @AKA yes checked your answer its working fine while used single one, but with multiple orderby fields it is not working ....

Comment: @AKA .. updated the question can you please check and corrct where went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the `ng-repeat` is `"p in peoples"` and not `"peoples in p"`. Change your `priorityArray` as shown below. Use the code below, works perfectly:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.peoples = [
            { 
               'priority': 'H'},
            {  
               'priority': 'M'},
            { 
               'priority': 'L'},
            { 
               'priority': 'NO GO'},
           {
               'priority': 'H'},
           {
               'priority': 'M'
            },
];

var priorityArray = { 'H': 1, 'M': 2, 'L': 3, 'NO GO': 4}; 
 
var toggled = false;

$scope.filterPriority = function () {
  if(toggled){
    $scope.peoples.sort(function (a, b) {
       return (priorityArray[a.priority] || Infinity ) - (priorityArray[b.priority] || Infinity);
    });
   }else{
     $scope.peoples.sort(function (a, b) {
       return (priorityArray[b.priority] || Infinity ) - (priorityArray[a.priority] || Infinity);
    });
   }   
  toggled = !toggled;
  };
        
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   <table>
    <tr>
      <th><a ng-click="filterPriority()">priority</a></th>
      <tr ng-repeat="p in peoples"><td>{{p.priority}}</td></tr>
   </table>
    
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: It is working thanks for the answer. and more question i have common sorting  on other columns and it is preventing priorirty filter. Updated the code please check

Comment: @AKA .. updated the question can you please check and corrct where went wrong – yaswanth 34 mins ago